# Partitioning A set into overlapping sets

Tags: algorithms

Given a set $A$ with $A_1....A_M$ elements in it. The set elements are distributed in $N$ sets with variable length. Elements can be in repeated in different sets.

Eg : $A={1,2,3,4}$
distributed into $2$ sets :

$B={1,2,3}$

$C={2,3,4}$

I have to find how many pairs (2 sets)out of these $N$ sets can make $A$ after their union.

The most obvious solution is to check every pair. But I want to know if the time can be reduced somehow ?

Comment: The problem I see is that your worstcase output is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ That mean without restrictions on $A$ an algorithm can not beat comparing each pair.

Comment: @the_architect Does the restriction that all sets have elements from $A_1...A_m$ only can bring improvisation ?

Comment: I have a strong feeling of deja-vu but somehow I can't find the question anymore. Someone asked a similar question by modeling the sets as binary vectors, and wanted to find any pair of vectors such that an OR operation would yield the $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ vector. I answered a method to find invalid pairs that had a slightly better complexity than the naive $\mathcal O(n^2m)$, I think it was something like $\mathcal O(n^2+Lm+nm)$, where $L$ is the number of invalid pairs.

Comment: An interesting question here, is whether the smaller sets have some sort of constraint on them. In your example, both $B$ and $C$ contains consecutive numbers. If every set is like that, there may be some clever way to sort the smaller sets, and validate/invalidate several pairs at once using only one comparison instead of many.

Comment: @N.Bach No, the sets don't necessarily contain consecutive numbers but they strictly  contain numbers between $A_1$ to $A_m$,both inclusive.
Also I would like to decrease the worst case complexity from $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @N.Bach That's because it's a question of an ongoing contest :/ I've flagged it. (Relevant question link -> https://www.codechef.com/JUNE17/problems/UNIONSET)